# Set Cordova app name, identifier from hook

Tags: android, cordova

I have a Cordova project and would like to automate changing the name and identifier of my app based on an environment var I set at build time, so that I can push separate apps like "MyApp (staging)" or "MyApp (dev)" to my device.

I assumed that by manipulating the platform-specific `platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml`, using cordova's `ConfigParser` class, I could make this config change without having to edit my version-controlled master `config.xml`.

But no matter what hook I do this in, the name & id that end up on the device come from the master `config.xml`.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

Changing values in `platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml` will have no effect because the `cordova prepare` operation uses the "master" `/config.xml`: `<widget id="your_app_id">` is injected into `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` as `<manifest package="your_app_id">` and `<name>Your App Name</name>` is injected into `platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml` as `<string name="app_name">Your App Name</string>`.

So you need would need to modify these files using an `after_prepare` hook, rather than the `res/xml/config.xml`.

Comment: Interesting. Is `res/xml/config.xml` used for anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think my idea won't work; if you change the app id, then when the app is compiled it'll expect the source files to be on that path. All in all, I think it's probably more trouble than it's worth.

I'm better off just one-off altering the value in `config.xml` in `before_prepare`, and then adding an `after_prepare` hook to change it back.